# Standalone Java application with HTML front end

Tags: java, javascript, html

I want to develop a standalone java application, with web browser as front end. This application will run locally and won't be making any remote server calls. I'm essentially using java, as web-browser cannot perform file operations.

I want this application to be portable: no need of installation. Just  copying a folder should be enough. I want to know how it can be done, how will javascript communicate with java code.

Comment: HTML with flash can perform file operation and so can signed JAVA applets

Comment: You can use standard servlets and WAR packaging to later embed Tomcat or Jetty. Standalone and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In continuation of @Quentin's answer.

Yes, you need web server.

There are 2 principal architectures:

- Create stand alone application with embedded web server
- Create ordinary web application and run it on proprietary web server.

IMHO I think that the second approach is better, however it strongly depend on your application functionality.

You can take jetty or grizzly as a web container. Both can run as in embedded or stand alone modes. You are welcome to share other details of your application with the community if you need concrete advises concerning to the design of your application.

Comment: I agree that the second suggestion would be best. But you dont need a proprietary web server to do that. JSP server Tomcat for example is published under Apache License.

Answer (score 0):

The application would need to implement an HTTP server. Then all communication would be done over HTTP.

Comment: My requirements are pretty straight forward.

Comment: @johnknaan — I didn't say the requirements were complex.

Answer (score 0):

Write a small web application as you need and Deploy it using [Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Downloading+Jetty). Jetty is a pure Java-based HTTP server and Java Servlet container. You can use it by embedded mode also.

Deployment is so easy if you use [Jetty-Runner](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Using_Jetty_Runner)

```
java -jar jetty-runner.jar my.war
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a local web server. Take JavaFX (embedded webkit) and implement a URL protocol handler for say "myprotocol". Then you can access it from the browser using something myprotocol://xxx.yyy.zzz